# Suddenly after implementing firebase many import statements becomes unused and can't resolve many symbols

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio

I'm new to Android, Was learning from youtube from following playlist

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d1T0ptCAs8A&list=PLraJmOvF9eeGyVClKdBaVU6O_XqQjNboS&index=5

In 4th video it was teaching to add Firebase, but it was old method as I got some new option on Firebase(Firebase was saying It needs only classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0')

suddenly after adding this line in build.graddel in project I saw that my previously working code have some errors

[image: Error]

[image: Build Gradle app]

[image: build Gradle Project]

I tried Invalidate cashes and restart, cleaned projects and rebuild.

Comment: problem was same as I just explained, I thought AndroidX will help so I migrated it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are mixing support library and androidx
 either use androidx(recommended) or support library
follow https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate guide and after this make sure to make appropriate changes in layout xml files also.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the dependencies with androidx starting. Because androidx is a different library than support library. You should only include one of them.